# Git freezing on push

Tags: git, github

I have this, then it freezes up

```
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1.09 GiB | 16.58 MiB/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Don't know how to fix this, I've uploaded stuff to git before and didn't run into this.

Comment: Have you checked your internet connection? Also, check if your remote server is down?

Comment: The message you quoted is not a problem, how many time you waited?

Comment: Like half an hour, is it just being slow? It's a decent sized file as I'm using git lfs. And what do you mean if my remote server is down exactly? Still sorta new to everything.

Comment: Your Git is not *frozen*, your Git is *done*. Your Git is waiting for the other Git, the one to which it just sent your commits, to send back an announcement. That other Git either takes your Git's requests and acts on them, or rejects the requests. Your Git then reports this result to you. Your Git is waiting for them to make their decision. There's nothing you can do about this—it's all up to them.

Comment: Well, you're uploading a very big file (1GB), depends on your connection it might be very slow. 

Since you don't have any errors yet I think it is the reason. By the way what is it? The biggest project I've seen was much more lightweight.

Comment: It's a Unity project. And torek, i'm assuming you're referring to Github? You're making it sound all ominous.

Comment: Yep, you're waiting for GitHub to report back. It's not clear what *they* are waiting for but apparently they're waiting for something too. (You might look into any settings you have control over.)